# Android: google FCM disable send notification after many hours

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use google FCM for send notification

If user not connected to internet and i send notification, after user connected to internet, notification receive to that user device

I want only notification to users if the same moment connected to internet and not send after

My code :

```
function sendNotification($to,$title,$text,$data=""){
    $fcmMsg = array('body'=>$title,
                    'title'=>$text,
                    'sound'=>"default",
                    'click_action'=>'YOUR_ACTION',
                    'largeIcon'=>'ic_launcher',
                    'smallIcon'=>'ic_launcher');

    $fcmFields = array('to'=>$to,
                       'data'=>$data,
                       'priority'=>'high',
                       'notification'=>$fcmMsg);

    $headers = array('Authorization: key='.API_ACCESS_KEY,
                     'Content-Type: application/json');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fcmFields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, FCM stores the message and try to resend if the device regains connectivity. So, you should add time_to_live parameter in your payload with value of 0. It will tell the FCM server that the message should be sent right away. If the device is not connected to the FCM server or offline, FCM server will discard the message and will not send it anymore.